# closure that expects closure forces it to be 'static

Tags: rust

In this simple example, I took the care of making sure `DecoderProvider` is a function that expects a reference to a closure, so it expects `&Box<dyn Fn(&Option<&Arc<u8>>)>`. This way, it uses the closure very shortly, and thus do not require the closure to be borrowed for `'static`. But below, it looks like calling `decoder_provider(&provide_decoder);` forces `provide_decoder` to live longer than `fn main`, which contains `on_packet_render`. Why?

```
use std::sync::Arc;
pub type DecoderProvider = Arc<dyn Fn(&Box<dyn Fn(&Option<&Arc<u8>>)>)>;

fn main() {
    let on_packet_render =
        Arc::new(|packet: Option<Box<u8>>| {
            //render packet here
        });
    let decoder = Arc::new(0);
    let decoder_provider:DecoderProvider = Arc::new(
        move |b: &Box<dyn Fn(&Option<&Arc<u8>>)>| {
            b(&Some(&decoder));
        },
    );
    let provide_decoder: Box<dyn Fn(&Option<&Arc<u8>>)> = 
        Box::new(|decoder| {
            on_packet_render(None);
        });
    
    decoder_provider(&provide_decoder);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0016a84b46a1eaee96e065596ec07243

```
error[E0597]: `on_packet_render` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:13
   |
10 |     let decoder_provider:DecoderProvider = Arc::new(
   |                          --------------- type annotation requires that `on_packet_render` is borrowed for `'static`
...
16 |         Box::new(|decoder| {
   |                  --------- value captured here
17 |             on_packet_render(None);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
21 | }
   | - `on_packet_render` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trait object, like that in `Arc<dyn Fn(...)>` is `'static` by default. The `|decoder| { ... }` closure only uses `on_packet_render` *by reference* and therefore is not `'static`. The fix is to *move* `on_packet_render` into the closure:

```
let provide_decoder: Box<dyn Fn(&Option<&Arc<u8>>)> = 
    Box::new(move |decoder| {
          // ^^^^
        on_packet_render(None);
    });
```

Comment: Do you know where lifetimes of traits is documented nowadays? It used to be in a section of TRPL titled [Advanced Lifetimes](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html) but that seems to have been removed in the current edition

Comment: @harmic yeah looks like its not mentioned in the book anymore, but the behavior is defined in the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes).